# Getting a reference collections in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My application has three collections Users, Channels and Feeds in MongoDB

Users can be registered for Channels. so Channel will have bunch of reference ID of user who has registered for that Channel.

Channel has multiple feeds. Feed document has reference ID to channel.

I want to retrieve the User Feeds based the channel he is subscribed.
How do i achieve this in Mongoose?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ObjectId` schema type to reference documents in other collections. And then you can use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to populate those documents when you query the parent document. For instance:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    // Some fields
    channels: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Channel'}]
});
```

Then when you fetch a user, you can use [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) like this:

```
User.findById(user._id).populate('channels').exec(function(err, userWithChannels) {
    var channels = userWithChannels.channels;
    // Do your work
});
```

You should be able to reverse the relation if that's what you want instead.

Comment: Thanks. I have to do the same for getting Feeds in the channels right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that in all the models you need references to other collections.